# Cassandra repair read writes metrics

Tags: cassandra

when repairs are run in Cassandra, does the read and writes done for repair count in the read/write metrics? Repair has to read the table to build merkle tree, similarly when it has to do repair it has to write to the table, i think it might be. Am I correct?

If so, is there any way to identify such read/writes from regular read/writes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same question was asked on the [Cassandra user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r0b5458118b8a35c025bfb70d0eebb5a165b9ee33d25e109b5fa884c2%40%3Cuser.cassandra.apache.org%3E) and I'm posting my response here.

Not quite. Cassandra does a validation compaction for the merkle tree calculation. And it streams SSTables instead of individual mutations from one node to another to synchronise data between replicas. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra 3, the metrics from ***Read repairs***, can be obtained via JMX, in the Mbean ["org.apache.cassandra.metrics"](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsMonitoring.html#opsMonitoringJconsole__cstar-metrics), those operations don't affect the metrics of regular read/write operations.